# Remove highlighting for an "Interesting Tag" on Tags landing page (since they are all highlighted)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-watching, tag-highlighting

From the home page of Stackoverflow I am shown my "Interesting" tags in the upper right corner and they are highlighted in yellow among all the items.  This is useful as it allows me to distinguish them amongst the herd.

If I click on one of those tags, however, and am redirected to the landing page for that specific tag ALL of the items are highlighted.  Consider the principle that when everything is highlighted nothing is.

Comment: .. it could also ignore highlighting for search results, when tag is searched, and the post tags does not include another interesting tag

Answer (score 3):

I posted this as a question a moment ago and it was rightfully closed as  duplicate, but here's my 2 cents:

I signed up for Stack Overflow the other day and so far everything's great.

I have two primary flows with the site, outside of asking a question:

1. Read the "Most recent questions" page, looking for anything of interest.
2. Click on a tag with which I am familiar, looking for questions I may be able to contribute to.

I have added [python] and [beginner] to my interesting tags list, and the highlighting this provides is very useful during flow 1. It is not so useful when I click on [python] for flow 2 purposes, for obvious reasons.

It is not only silly to look at a full page of highlighted entries when I obviously already know they will have a given tag; it is an active loss of a useful feature - any articles tagged both [python] and [beginner] will not be differentiated visually, when clearly it would be nice if they were.

Comment: I agree. The highlighted items should be questions featuring other interested tags

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with Robert Harvey's answer.  The tags are highlighted in order to distinguish items in a list, much as a student might highlight important lines in a document.  If every line is equally important, no human student or assistant would highlight every single line.  It accomplishes nothing but decrease visibility.

Answer (score 2):

Questions on the tag page are no longer highlighted unless they also have one or more of your other favourite tags on them.

Answer (score 1):

I consider the current method of highlighting all of the items a feature, not a bug.  It follows the principle of least surprise.

Answer (score 0):

try [this greasemonkey script by Alconja](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49704/double-intensity-shading-for-questions-with-1-interesting-tags/49724#49724), it does at least emphasize the presence of further interesting tags