# Is it possible to not filter out ignored tags on a case-by-case basis?

Tags: support, search, ignored-tags

When I do a search, I see a full list of results, then after a second or two, the list seems to "filter."  I am guessing that it filters off my ignored tags.

Normally I think this is great.  However, sometimes I just want to see the full results (e.g. I usually don't care about C++ stuff, but on rare occasion I need to search for something C++-y).

Is there a way to see the whole list if I want to?

Comment: Use gift-shopping mode in one of the newer browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated [my greasemonkey script dealing with interesting/ignored questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49704/double-intensity-shading-for-questions-with-1-interesting-tags/49724#49724) to support this feature request. Basically now a "Toggle hidden" link appears just below the "Ignored Tags" form (on the right of the question list) that allows you to toggle between showing/hiding questions with ignored tags. Its a purely temporary setting (i.e. it still initially displays as per your user prefs and doesn't permanently change anything), so you can use it in one off situations like you describe.

Hope it's of some use to you...

Answer (score 0):

Not the greatest solution, but on those rare occasions when you want to include an ignored tag in your search you could log out and do your search with no preferences.

You could also temporarily uncheck the "Hide Ignored Tags" in your preferences.  This will cause questions with tags in your Ignore list to be grayed out instead of removed from the list.