# Should tags be more intelligent?

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, tags, ignored-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Provide “Keep Interesting Tags” option when “Hide Ignored Tags” enabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36954/provide-keep-interesting-tags-option-when-hide-ignored-tags-enabled)

I'll dive straight into an example. I have the tag "Java" hidden, I'm not interested in Java programming... in general. However, I do have "Android" marked as a tag I'm interested in. What currently happens is any question that is tagged as "Android" & "Java", I don't get to see. So I've had to remove "Java" from the list of tags I'm not interested in (which results in lots of questions I don't care about, with some that I do care about).

My proposal is to *not* hide any questions that have a tag I'm interested in - that should always be the most powerful criteria.

Duplicates:
[Tags: If "A" in My Tags, and "B" in Ignore, and a post has "A" and "B", I'd like to see it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26181/tags-if-a-in-my-tags-and-b-in-ignore-and-a-post-has-a-and-b-id-like)

[Provide "Keep Interesting Tags" option when "Hide Ignored Tags" enabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36954/provide-keep-interesting-tags-option-when-hide-ignored-tags-enabled)

Comment: How about going to the prefs tab in your profile and deselecting "Hide Ignored Tags"?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26181/tags-if-a-in-my-tags-and-b-in-ignore-and-a-post-has-a-and-b-id-like and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36954/provide-keep-interesting-tags-option-when-hide-ignored-tags-enabled both cover proposals for this functionality. I thought there was also one that specified it should be default to interesting > ignored, but I am unable to find that one right now.

Comment: @Grace Note: and I was just about to comment "Grace will certainly remember the dupes"

Comment: @Ami, how would that solve my problem? I would still end up with noise from tags I'm not interested in.
@Grace, thanks for the links. That's exactly what I'm talking about.

Comment: Another link (as a solution for you rather than as a duplicate), if you're up to using GreaseMonkey, might be [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57613/is-it-possible-to-not-filter-out-ignored-tags-on-a-case-by-case-basis).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to modify [Alconja's greasemonkey script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49704/double-intensity-shading-for-questions-with-1-interesting-tags/49724#49724) accordingly.