# Define your own color of tagged-interesting

Tags: discussion, tag-watching

I don't like the `tagged-interesting` css-Class color. It is so glimmering. Would be great to define your own color.

Comment: This is why Spider-Man invented userscripts. You can define your own colours right away without bothering anyone else with your poor taste.

Comment: I love my poor taste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be changed easily with Stylish for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108/):

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document domain("stackoverflow.com") {

.tagged-interesting { background-color: #eef !important; }

}
```

It also works with the [Chrome version](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) (specify the domain separately):

```
.tagged-interesting { background-color: #eef !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Alconja's greasemonkey script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/49704/146482), which also allows different colours depending on the amount of interesting tags in one question.