# Color questions based on the number of favorite tags

Tags: feature-request, design, tag-watching

When one of a question's tags are one of the tags I chose, the question is being colored to help the user notice that this question belongs to a tag he/she marked.

I think it is better if there are different colors to "more than 1 tag" match.

So, for 1 tag match - today's color.
2 tags - color 2.
3 tags - color 3. etc.

This will help the users to find more relevant questions more easily.

Moreover, if I chose tags like [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) or [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), then many questions are non-relevant for me. The coloring system might help me as a user to find questions more suitable for my expertise and knowledge.

Comment: A [related request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49704/double-intensity-shading-for-questions-with-1-interesting-tags) which asks for simply a difference between 1 and >1 favorite tags.

Comment: Thanks! I think it would've been better the solution was part of the website and not a greasemonkey script though. :-)

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest a slight modification: color question according to the **interesting tags / total ratio**.

If a question is purely about [some-tag-you-follow](/questions/tagged/some-tag-you-follow) and has only this tag, it is likely to be relevant to you => "full" color, while if it is also about [some-other-tag](/questions/tagged/some-other-tag) that you are not interested in, it will be a dimmed color.

My proposal would be a varying saturation/lightness/opacity of the same hue.

Comment: This depends on a non-guaranteed relationship between tags. For example, if I'm interested in [c#], a question tagged [c#] is probably of equal relevance to me as something tagged [c#] [strings], as I know about strings. Not necessarily if it was [sharepoint] [c#], though. Not all tags have the same style of relationship, so I don't think it would be wise to base this kind of system on such an assumption.