# Colouring system to further distinguish how many of your tags a question matches

Tags: feature-request, tags, questions, highlighting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Color questions based on the number of favorite tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85676/color-questions-based-on-the-number-of-favorite-tags)

Okay, so I really like the fact that on the new Question List questions that match your interesting tags are coloured orange.

What my request is, that based on how many of your interesting tags match that question, the colour should darken/possibly transform into a different colour? Maybe even a % relevancy to the left of the question to highlight how relevant it is? On the back of that, maybe even a relevancy sorting?

I sometimes find that I miss questions that I'm really interested in purely because there's a sea of orange on my homepage and if I don't go through them with a fine tooth comb, I won't see a potential question that matches 4/5 of my interesting tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grid will turn into a rainbow. I like the idea but think it should be more subtle. Maybe a bar to the right. The more full it is, the more relevant the question.

Excuse the (terrible) graphics, but maybe this sort of effect:
[image]