# How about a finer-grained favorite question/tag system?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, tag-watching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Double-intensity shading for questions with >1 Interesting tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49704/double-intensity-shading-for-questions-with-1-interesting-tags)

I like being able to highlight questions with favorite tags. But I'm not 100% happy with it.

Since I have [java](/questions/tagged/java) as a favorite tag, I see many questions that I'm not so interested in, for example [android](/questions/tagged/android) questions. Other questions however, like the ones on [spring](/questions/tagged/spring) I like. But if I remove the [java](/questions/tagged/java) tag from my favorites, I might miss some interesting general Java questions.

The problem here is that the highlight system is binary: Either a question is highlighted or it's not. As in information retrieval, you run into problems with an "exact" (binary) system, as you can't control precision and recall easily.

So here is my proposition: Make the highlight/favorite system finer-grained by introducing multiple levels of favoriteness. This would highlight questions strongly that match multiple favorite tags (for example questions on Spring *and* Java) but would still highlight questions "only" on Java a bit.

Well, what do you think?

(An extension of this would be to go to a continuous scale and enable the user to specify *how much* he likes (or dislikes) a tag which would also make it possible to "eliminate" a question's favoriteness due to one tag (Java) if it also has another one (Android). But this is probably an overkill.)

---

**Edit:** I'd like to point out that the basic version of this is not complicated at all and can probably be implemented in some presentation layer only.

So far, "interesting" questions have a CSS class `tagged-interesting`. The only thing to do would be to add two or three levels with the respective classes, (e.g. `tagged-interesting-1`, `tagged-interesting-2` and `tagged-interesting-3`) and style them accordingly.

Comment: I think that noting multiple favorite tags is a good idea, and I can think of times it would have been good for my view of a SE site. But “specify how much” would be overcomplicating.

Comment: Can't you just ignore the `[android]` tag?

Comment: The point is not that I absolutely don't like android, but rather that I'd like to see quickly if a question is "very interesting" to me, e.g. if it has multiple of my favorite tags.