# Inline tags lead to larger line-heights - Intentional?

Tags: discussion, tags, markdown, design

I noticed that using a bunch of tags within a question or answer screws up the appearance of the text since the lines get higher. See this question for example: [How about a finer-grained favorite question/tag system?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146818/195634). Here's a screenshot:

[image: tags in text - now]

Is this the intentional behavior? Because I think removing the `line-height: 2.4;` property of the `.post-tag` CSS class leads to a much more pleasant text image:

[image: tags in text - proposed]

(You can easily try that out yourself if you have Firebug or something similar.)

Comment: The problem with removing it is that [this can happen](http://i.stack.imgur.com/B6VOC.png).

Comment: So would it be an option to shrink the height of the tags a little bit?