# Change highlighting of an interesting tag when browsing the list of questions with that tag

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, tag-highlighting

Instead, highlight those questions that additionally contain *another* interesting tag.

*I know about [Remove highlighting for an “Interesting Tag” on Tags landing page (since they are all highlighted)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36396/remove-highlighting-for-an-interesting-tag-on-tags-landing-page-since-they-are), but I don't suggest removing but changing the highlighting.*

Comment: Related, for general scenario instead of just the tag search: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49704/double-intensity-shading-for-questions-with-1-interesting-tags

Comment: @Grace Note: true. If you posted that as an answer, I'd accept it

Comment: Do you mean Alconja's script in the linked question?

Comment: @Grace Note: yes, exactly that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alconja's Greasemonkey Script [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49704/double-intensity-shading-for-questions-with-1-interesting-tags/49724#49724) should be sufficient for your needs.