# Where did the yellow background of interesting tags go?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, tag-watching

Let's have a look at a screenshot I just made:

[image: screenshot showing problem; but if you can't see (this), you can't see the problem, so this alt text is useless anyway]

Until now, when viewing a page containing questions marked with an ‘interesting tag’, all questions got a nice, soothing yellow background to let me know that all questions contain interesting tags. I know this signal is redundant on a page where I view only questions containing at least one interesting tag, but I grew accustomed to the yellowish view.

However, I just visited SO again and clicked an interesting tag. To my amazement, not all questions got a yellow background, creating a sick zebra-like pattern in front of me, that looks distracting. I guess that something like [this question's proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56115/change-highlighting-of-an-interesting-tag-when-browsing-the-list-of-questions-wit) got fulfilled, highlighting only questions that contain other interesting tags, but this looks confusing to me. As I can't find anything about this on Meta, it might as well be a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was changed [yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72587/why-is-stack-overflow-suddenly-orange/72593#72593):

> To alleviate the "everything's orange" problem, if one of your interesting/frequented/ignored tags is in the list of tags on a `/questions/tagged/{tags}` page highlighting for that tag will be disabled.
>
> For instance, if your interesting tags are `java` and `android`, going to [Questions Tagged java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) will cause only `android` tagged questions to be highlighted.
>
> This code will go out with our next build.