# When I list the questions in one of my favorite tags, only some of them are highlighted

Tags: support, tags, tag-watching, tag-highlighting

It used to be when I list the questions in one of my favorite tags, all of them were highlighted. A few weeks/months ago this changed. (Why this matters: I'm trained to mostly look at the highlighted questions, because that's the tags I know something about. Now habit makes me skip over questions in the tag I know most about. It drives me nuts, but I can't help it, Mr. Pavlov seems to be much stronger than I am.)

At first I thought it's trouble with my browser, so I cleared its cache. In the past that has helped whenever I had trouble with SO. But it didn't help this time. So I'm forced that it's either a bug or [a feature I haven't heard about](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77025/can-we-have-a-notification-for-new-features-please) and which I don't understand. Previous experience suggests that it is a feature, but I still don't understand it.

So why aren't all questions highlighted anymore when I few those of one of my favorite tags?

Comment: It's a bug.  I didn't get very far with it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72700/interesting-tag-highlighting-appears-random-on-or-queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a feature, see the "update" section in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72587/why-is-stack-overflow-suddenly-orange/72593#72593).

Comment: Ah, Ok, that makes sense now. Thanks.