# Highlighting for 'f#' tag

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tag-highlighting

I have 'f#' in my list of interesting tags. I've just noticed that questions tagged with 'f#' don't get highlighted.

Is this expected? **edit:** apparently, yes

Comment: [Everywhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-to-f%23), or just on the [F# tag page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/f%23)?

Comment: Stone Just on the F# tag page. It's possible that the first time I used the F# tag page was 30 seconds before posting this question, in which case I would guess this behaviour was by design.

Comment: Ah, in that case see [this related question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72687/150235), as the lack of highlighting on that page is now `[status-bydesign]` per [these changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72587/why-is-stack-overflow-suddenly-orange/72593#72593). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Tim Stone](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150235/tim-stone) noted, this is a (relatively) recent change and by design.